# In your ssh config is it possible to have one host entry for multiple machines on the same domain

Tags: ssh, hosts

I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Host *
    HostName *.mydomain.com
    ...
```

So I can type something like

```
ssh test
ssh ci
ssh dev
```

Instead of having to type

```
ssh test.mydomain.com
ssh ci.mydomain.com
ssh dev.mydomain.com
```

Right now I have separate entries for each one, but we have dozens of machines, so I'd rather have a default rather than have to duplicate everything so many times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing this with ssh, use the /etc/resolv.conf file

Add a line saying

```
search mydomain.com
```

What this does is wherever you don't enter a full domain name, it will use this suffix to work out the full name, effectively appending `.mydomain.com` to `ci` when you do `ssh ci`.

Comment: Can you have multiple searches in a resolv.conf? I'm on an AD domain that is set as my search currently.

Comment: Yes you can, this is the purpose of search domains, and many sites run multiple concurrent domains that need to be checked to find the right host

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with following config:

```
Host *
HostName %h.mydomain.com
```