# SSH Config setting default user for multiple hosts under the same domain + aliases

Tags: linux, ssh

This thread: [In your ssh config is it possible to have one host entry for multiple machines on the same domain](https://superuser.com/questions/368062/in-your-ssh-config-is-it-possible-to-have-one-host-entry-for-multiple-machines-o) explained the 'aliases' part of my question, I was wondering if it's possible to set default username AS well as use domain aliases, so I can simply have to write something like:

`ssh subdomain`

I have the following in my /etc/resolv.conf file:

`search my_cool_domain.com`

and the following in my ssh_config file:

```
Host *.my_cool_domain.com
    User deploy
```

So I figured the following will work:

`ssh subdomain`

will try to connect to `subdomain.my_cool_domain.com` with user `deploy` but this does not work for some reason.

Although the following:

`ssh deploy@subdomain` does work, as well as: 
`ssh subdomain.my_cool_domain.com`

Any idea how can I fix this (If it's even possible) in an elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The patterns after the keyword "Host" are not resolved in anyway to real host names, so you cannot detect that a subdomain that your dns lookup is configured for it actually a subdomain of your main domain.

From the ssh_config manpage -

```
         ... The host is the hostname argument given on the command line (i.e. the
         name is not converted to a canonicalized host name before match-
         ing).
```

Your alternative is to, either

1. Use "Host *" and set the default username for all hosts.
2. When/if you have some kinds of prefixes to your subdomains, use "Host pfx1* pfx2*".
3. Configure your shell completion and always use full host names, "Host *.mydomain" and "ssh subdomain" that completes it to "ssh subdomain.mydomain".
4. Shell aliases and function can also be used to add the ".mydomain" part automagically. For example, "ssh-alias subdomain" that is an alias for "ssh subdomain.mydomain".

Answer (score 2):

just use a combined solution with properly setup ssh_config + resolv.conf:

1 . setup /etc/resolv.conf

```
search my_cool_domain.com
```

2 . setup your ssh_config for mapping between hosts and users

```
Host subdomain1
    User deploy1

Host subdomain2
    User deploy2
```

this way `ssh subdomain1` will use the required user `deploy1` and the host will be qualified to it's full name by `resolv.conf`